# ServiceStack OAuth2 provider implementation

Tags: authentication, oauth, servicestack

I have application developed with ServiceStack that used credential authentication for login. Now I need services of application to be consumed by other app.

OAuth2 provider seems best to allow api access. As such ServiceStack do not have OAuth2 provider by default but it allows to implement our own OAuth2Provider. But, till now I could not get good example for the same.

So, I am looking for good example or link to implement the OAuth2Provider in ServiceStack.

Comment: This is one thought to register for app2 within app1. Need to decide once registered and got credentials and also can log in, within same session fine but how to login later as can not save username/password anywhere. So, there must be way with ServiceStack to handle this situation.

Comment: Can you use a shared `ICacheClient` and `IAuthRepository'?  Then your auth token in one will be valid for the other.

Comment: jklemmack, both applications have their own UserAuth managed separately. In this case it seems we can not share IAuthRepository for both apps